# How to modify the shape of a control widget in FabricJS?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm using FabricJS in my web application. As I draw shapes, I notice that the control widget for all the objects are rectangular. Can the shape of a control widget be modified to fit the actual shape of the object? Say, a circle with a circular control widget.

I went through the [Controls Customization demo](http://fabricjs.com/controls-customization). But there is no option to modify the shape of a control widget.

I need to modify the shape of the control widgets for the following purpose:
In my application whenever an object is clicked, its fill colour is toggled between black and white. In this case(refer the image below), because the circle has a rectangular control widget, clicking the pointed pixel selects the circle instead of the rectangle. I also hide the control widget from appearing by using `hasControls` property. So, the user will not know anything about the control widget. So, is the shape of the control widget editable?
[image: FabricJS Demo - Controls]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to do that with fabric.js without writing a whole bunch of extra code. Fabric.js always draws a rectangle bounding box and uses it for selection controls. However, since you're planning on hiding the controls anyway, it sounds like you might be better off using [perPixelTargetFind](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#perPixelTargetFind).

> When true, object detection happens on per-pixel basis rather than on
>   per-bounding-box

Here's a quick demo:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
  perPixelTargetFind: true
})

const circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50,
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  stroke:'green',
  fill: 'white',
  hasControls: false,
  hasBorders: false
})

const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 200,
  height: 150,
  left: 50,
  top: 25,
  stroke: 'green',
  fill: 'black',
  hasControls: false,
  hasBorders: false
})

canvas.on('mouse:down', (e) => {
  const obj = e.target
  if (obj) {
    obj.set({
      fill: obj.fill === 'white' ? 'black' : 'white'
    })
    canvas.requestRenderAll()
  }
})

canvas.add(circle, rect)
circle.bringToFront()
canvas.requestRenderAll()
```

```css
body {
  background: ivory;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is Great! I was dispatching a mouse down event on Canvas to deselect the object after clicking it. Looks like `preserveObjectStacking` would do the job well.